# Making sure that dynamic alocation is successful

Tags: c, embedded, malloc, avr

I have global pointer to the array, lets say that it has declaration like shown below.

```
uint8_t * g_ptr;
```

I have some function

```
void foo(uint8_t no_devices);
```

which will be used to allocate arrays of desired size.

Pointer returned by function malloc() will be stored in g_ptr. This will work like champ if dynamic allocation is successful, but what if malloc() return NULL value.

I have an idea how to handle this kind of error and just want to get your opinion.

```
do
{
  g_ptr = (uint8_t *) malloc(no_devices * 8);
}
while(g_ptr == NULL)
```

Is this good idea, or is there another way to handle this kind of errors?

I am using avr-gcc compiler.

Comment: Well, that's likely to eat all your CPU and drain your battery, so I guess it will "fix" the problem by shutting down the device after a bit.

Comment: Whea,  usually when malloc return NULL it mean that memory is exhausted so you're screwed. In an other hand I never use dynamic allocation on microcontroller, I would have done a array or MAX_DEVICES size..

Comment: I don't think this is a good strategy. When `malloc` returns `NULL` it's usually because you are out of memory, the fact that you keep requestion memory won't probably change the outcome. At least put a delay of 1 sec and hope that in that time other processes ended/freed the memory. Most of the times that means that you program cannot continue anyway, printing an error message and exiting would be more appropriate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726006/6385115

Comment: Don't use malloc().  Figure out what memory you need and allocate it statically.  If it doesn't fit, use less memory or design in a MCU part with more.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I did have version of the code where I used Macro to define size of the array, and after reading this answers I will use that version instead of this one.

Comment: It depends on environment. In FreeRTOS you can control allocation strategies as it delivers malloc itself. You could also wrap malloc with own version that does safety check and halts/restart MCU on such event.