# Need an example of using mmem in Contiki

Tags: c, heap-memory, contiki, cooja

I am developing code to use in the COOJA simulator. I used `malloc()` for all of the dynamic memory allocations. While the simulation is running, COOJA motes restart periodically and at last I get an error which tells me the reason is I'm using `malloc()`.

I'm thinking of using Contiki's specific memory allocation class named "mmem". I could not found any example of using it. Here is an example in which I used `malloc()` to allocate memory to a string named `sent`.

How do I replace using `malloc()` to use `mmem` instead of `malloc()`?

```
   char *sent;
   sent = (char*)malloc(120);
   strncpy(sent , "example" , 7);
   strncat(sent , "|", 1);
```

Comment: Why dont you just allocate 120 bytes on the stack?

Comment: in my case, there would be a lot of conversion between character and string, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: I don’t think I understand. If you know the allocation size upfront (which your example code suggests), why not just allocate on the stack? Embedded development on low-resource devices and dynamic allocation usually ends with fragmentation which leads to exhaustion, which may be what caused your crash. Even Contiki’s documentation mentions this. Nonetheless, I assume you’ve read this guide: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Memory-allocation#The_mmem_Managed_Memory_Allocator ?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand the solution that you're refering to. would you please explain how I can allocate on the stack? honestly I don't understand what you meant by "stack".

Comment: stack vs heap is a central concept in C programming and I’ll have a hard time explaining it here in only 600 characters. Basically instead of `char* sent = malloc(120);` you do `char sent[120];` etc.

Comment: the code's logic is working with strings. strings would be sent and received, concatenated and edited a lot. by using ```char sent[120]```, I should deal with 120 characters and change it to string and change it back many times. I chose pointers instead of arrays to make it simple to work with strings and avoid complexity.

Comment: In C a char-array is a string? In `char sent[120];`, `sent` is a char-pointer just as well as if you had done `char* sent = malloc(120);`. The memory is just allocated on the stack instead of the heap.

Comment: I'm new to C, so I don't understand what happens with heap or stack. but I learnt that we represent a string using a char array from here : [ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings ] . Am I wrong?

Comment: That is exactly my point: a string is a char-array whether it is allocated on the stack or on the heap. Heap allocation is just a bad idea on resource-constrained devices, so I advise you to allocate statically instead, regardless of any perceived simplicity-benefits from dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2):

From [Contiki’s github Wiki](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Memory-allocation#The_mmem_Managed_Memory_Allocator)

Here is an example of how to use the managed memory allocator:

```
 #include "contiki.h"
 #include "lib/mmem.h"

 static struct mmem mmem;

 static void
 test_mmem(void)
 {
   struct my_struct {
     int a;
   } my_data, *my_data_ptr;

   if(mmem_alloc(&mmem, sizeof(my_data)) == 0) {
     printf("memory allocation failed\n");
   } else {
     printf("memory allocation succeeded\n");
     my_data.a = 0xaa;
     memcpy(MMEM_PTR(&mmem), &my_data, sizeof(my_data));
     /* The cast below is safe only if the struct is packed */
     my_data_ptr = (struct my_struct *)MMEM_PTR(&mmem);
     printf("Value a equals 0x%x\n", my_data_ptr->a);
     mmem_free(&mmem);
   }
 }
```

> The example above shows a basic example of how the managed memory
>   library can be used. On line 4, we allocate a variable, mmem, that
>   identifies the managed memory object that we are about to allocate. On
>   line 13, we use the mmem variable as an argument for mmem_alloc() to
>   allocate space for a structure of sizeof(my_data) bytes. If the
>   allocation succeeded, we copy the values from an existing structure
>   into the allocated structure, pointed to by MMEM_PTR(&mmem).
>   Individual members of allocated structure can then be accessed by a
>   type cast of MMEM_PTR(&mmem) to struct my_struct *, as shown on line
>   20. Note that the cast is only safe if the struct is packed. The managed memory is finally deallocated on line 21 by calling
>   mmem_free().

.

**EDIT:**

From the code you've pasted in the comments, there is no need to use `malloc` or the `mmem`-module. Just allocate on the stack. Maybe try something like this instead:

```
/* Allocate memory on the stack */
char sent[120];

/* Manipulate strings */
strncpy(sent , "reqid" , 5); 
strncat(sent, "|", 1); 

/* Send UDP packet */
uip_udp_packet_send(mcast_conn, sent, strlen(sent)); 

/* Print out string sent */
printf(" (msg: %s)\n", sent);
```

**EDIT 2:**

[Here is a page on heap vs stack.](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) and [here is a stackoverflow question about dynamic allocation on embedded devices and the problems it involves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725923/how-bad-is-it-to-use-dynamic-datastuctures-on-an-embedded-system).

Comment: actually I saw this example. to clarify the problem I insert my code here: `
    struct my_struct {
    char * sent;
       } my_data, *my_data_ptr;
       strncpy(my_data.sent , "reqid" , 5);
       strncat(my_data.sent, "|", 1);
memcpy(MMEM_PTR(&mmem), &my_data, sizeof(my_data));
my_data_ptr = (struct my_struct *)MMEM_PTR(&mmem);
uip_udp_packet_send(mcast_conn, my_data_ptr->sent, strlen(my_data_ptr->sent));
printf(" (msg: %s)\n", my_data_ptr->sent);
mmem_free(&mmem);` 
I expect to see "mg : reqid|" in the output but the output in NULL. I want to know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @mahshid Can you please edit your question to include the code you’ve tried? You are missing a call to `mmem_init()` and `mmem_alloc(...)` I think...? Again I suggest you try using static allocation instead of dynamic allocation, for the reasons mentioned in my other comments (fragmentation leading to memory exhaustion).

Comment: sorry for the bad representation, I tried several times but I could not understand how it works.I added mmem_init() and mmem_allocate() but it's still the same.
```C
struct my_struct { char * sent; 
} my_data, *my_data_ptr;  
mmem_init();  
mmem_alloc(&mmem, 120);  
strncpy(my_data.sent , "reqid" , 5);  
strncat(my_data.sent, "|", 1);  
memcpy(MMEM_PTR(&mmem), &my_data, sizeof(my_data));  
my_data_ptr = (struct my_struct *)MMEM_PTR(&mmem);
uip_udp_packet_send(mcast_conn, my_data_ptr->sent, strlen(my_data_ptr->sent));
printf(" (msg: %s)\n", my_data_ptr->sent);
mmem_free(&mmem);
```

Comment: @mahshid I have updated my answer with some code I think could work instead. I don't have anything running Contiki, so I can't test it myself, but I don't think you need the `mmem`-module from what you've posted.